# Catalyst 13.1 Installation on Ubuntu 12.04 : debclean not found

Tags: ati

I am trying to install the AMD Catalyst version 13.1 driver on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (desktop version).

I have downloaded the *.run file corresponding to the driver version.

amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run

I am following the instructions to install Catalyst here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/126513

All the dependencies were downloaded as well.

When I run:

It fails to build the package with the error:

```
Generating package: Ubuntu/precise
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
....
....
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

I downloaded devscripts as well to fix the error related to debclean.

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
devscripts is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 189 not upgraded.
```

As you can see, I have the latest version of debclean installed. Even after this, it fails to build the package when I run with the same error specific to "debclean not found". How can I fix this error?

```
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try running debclean in a terminal, and possibly: `sudo apt-get install debclean` (not sure if that package exists, but it follows package name convention)

Comment: There is no package with the name, debclean. From what I have read on various internet resources, in order to install debclean, we need to install devscripts using apt-get. However, I am not sure why even after install devscripts, the error for debclean persists.

Comment: Looks like it's in the devscripts package, indeed.

Comment: Before running the ati installer, do: sudo apt-get install debhelper dh-modaliases execstack

Answer (score 1):

Just try this [link.](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Proprietary_Drivers_a.k.a._Catalyst.2Ffglrx) It may help. At least it will guide you how to cover the problem.

Regards.

P.S.:  I have ATI  Mobility Radeon HD 4xxx series and it worked for my cause.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.